# Get src attribute of img tag from html string , without loading image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

In jQuery we can use `find()` to filter `img` tags and retrive their `src` attributes, But doing this causes the images to load.

I actually **get the html string from feeds**, so I can't trust if it's well formed.

**I tried XML Parser :**

```
function searchXml(xmlStr, selector) {
  var parser, xmlDoc;
  if(window.DOMParser) {
   parser = new DOMParser();
   xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
  } else {
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async = false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr); 
  }
  return $(xmlDoc).find(selector);
}    
console.log(searchXml('<p><img src="http://image.url/file.jpg" /></p>','img').attr('src'));
```

It is working fine for small HTML strings, but not with HTML from feeds.

Is there a reason why not?

Comment: @Jeff B I tagged PHP because , some solutions suggested php TIDY can be used.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't my edit.  It was suggested by someone else, and I approved it and fixed some spelling errors. :)  In either case, we can't read your mind, so if you are interested in a PHP solution, please say so in the question.

Comment: you could find src attributes by regexp `/src="(.+?)"/`

Comment: Thanks Ivan ,But regexp maynot always provide reliable results

Comment: If you can figure out why your HTML won't be accepted by the XML parser and fix that then it would work - the XML parser doesn't create an `Image` element when it sees an `img` tag.

Comment: I got "parse error mismatched tag expected : </img>" .. But as i said the html string, comes from feeds and is unpredictable